# how to get multiple field value in one field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table , post_tbl, tag_tbl, post_tag_tbl and as you know we can join them to get post tags name.
but i want to show 10 post each time for pagination, and show the tags name too.
we can do it with a  query to fetch 10 post and then for each post whit post id get the tags, but it is realy inefficient.
is there any way to get mysql fields as array, for example fields tags contain all tag names of post.

```
post_id      post_name     tags
1            post one      tag1,tag2,tag3
2            post two      tag3,tag2,tag5
```

what is best solution for this kind of problems?

Comment: see the article i added as answer

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)

This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(tags_name) as tag
from tags where tag_post_id = Xyz
```